# How to extract multiple email addresses from a web page using Jsoup?

Tags: java, regex, jsoup

I have list of sites from which i need to go to contact page and extract the email ids for each and every site using jsoup. I'm using the java.util.regex.Pattern to get email id code is shown below

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+").matcher(doc.toString());
if (m.find()) {             
 email= m.group();              
 System.out.println(email);
}
```

I encountered a some website where it contains multiple email addresses but above code gets only one email id which has encountered as first. I would like to get all the email id from that page.

I tried using below code but still getting all the junk

```
Elements elements =  doc.getElementsMatchingText(Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+"));
for(Element element: elements){
System.out.println(element.toString());
}
```

How can i get all the email ids from a web page?
please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `while` loop instead of `if` condition, so that it would do printing for each match.

```
while (m.find()) {             
 email= m.group();              
 System.out.println(email);
}
```

OR

```
while (m.find()) {                         
     System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```